# Active Record unexpected i18n error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, internationalization, activesupport

I am building a Ruby project that uses active record but not rails. Inside one of my tests I am trying the following:

```
it "fails with no driver name" do
  command = "Driver"
  expect {command_file.process_driver command}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
end
```

And here is the method I am trying to call

```
def process_driver command
  driver_name = command.split[1]
  Driver.create! :name => driver_name
end
```

I expect to be passing `:name => nil` to `Driver.create!` which should throw a `RecordInvalid` but instead I get `I18n::InvalidLocaleData`. Here is the backtrace

```
expected ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, got #<I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/r...ems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: expects it to return a hash, but does not> with backtrace:
  # ./command_file.rb:81:in `process_driver'
  # ./command_file.rb:63:in `block in process'
  # ./command_file.rb:51:in `each'
  # ./command_file.rb:51:in `each_with_index'
  # ./command_file.rb:51:in `process'
  # ./spec/command_file_spec.rb:60:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/command_file_spec.rb:60:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:75:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/spec_helper.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And here is my `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.13'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.3'
gem 'pry', '~> 0.10.4'
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.6'
gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.5'

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

I have no locale files of my own.

Any idea what's going on? I am not attempting any kind of translation in this project. I also don't understand why a locale file provided by `active_support` should fail. I'd be happy to simply disable i18n somehow if that were possible but I don't know how. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: do you have any `.yml` or config files? Could you attach a `.gemfile`?

Comment: @MaxL. I have no `.yml` or config files. I've added my `Gemfile` to the question

Comment: Anything in your `config/locales` folder? Empty `en.yml` file, perhaps?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't have a `config/locales` folder. I'm not intending to even have internationalization.

Comment: Can you verify that the {your-ruby-gempath}/active_support-5.1.3/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml file exists on your machine? Did you switch ruby versions with rb env -  do you need to run `bundle install` with your current version of ruby to get active_support installed? Or else switch back to the correct rb env ruby version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what ever reason `:en` was not set as my default locale. I fixed that in my `spec_helper.rb` by adding `I18n.default_locale = 'en'`:

```
I18n.default_locale = 'en' # <--- add this line

RSpec.configure do |config|
    # config here...
end
```

I realize this doesn't fix the larger problem of why the locale file from `active_support` was not loading, but my challenge was simply to make the error go away, not to use i18n